# How to draw star with label in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to draw ***star** in label as the image below

[image]

I have tried

`Text("5 *",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green),)`

But I don't know how I can embed ***(Star)** with label ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the icon class for that

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Text("5),
    Icon(Icons.star),
  ]

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Container(
              width: 80,
            height:50,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.green[700],
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                Text('5',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.white)
              ])),
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Just check this code :

The star icon can be obtained using this plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/material_design_icons_flutter#-readme-tab-

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),color: Colors.green),
                width: 100,
                height: 50,

                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text('5',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ),
                           Icon(MdiIcons.star,color: Colors.white,),
                    ],
                  ),
              ),
```

Comment: Thanks for effort. But as good practise try not to use third party.

Comment: you can use the inbuild icons, this library has wide variety of icons. so its on you how you use it.